# jmeter's xml log using ant and browser looks different

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, ant, jmeter

I made some changes in `jmeter-results-report_21.xsl` to show me the test case name in the html report. It works fine when open directly in the browser, but when I use the ant to generate the report, it's grouping the case test name in the top of the page and the URLs above. It's like if the for was not nested.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/testResults/*[not(@tn = preceding::*/@tn)]">
<xsl:variable name="labelCaso" select="@tn" />
<tr><xsl:value-of select="$labelCaso" /></tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/testResults/*[not(@lb = preceding::*/@lb)] ">
        <xsl:variable name="label" select="@lb"/>
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(../*[@lb = current()/@lb] [attribute::tn=$labelCaso])" />
        <xsl:variable name="failureCount" select="count(../*[@lb = current()/@lb][attribute::s='false'][attribute::tn=$labelCaso])" />
        <xsl:variable name="successCount" select="count(../*[@lb = current()/@lb][attribute::s='true'][attribute::tn=$labelCaso])" />
        <xsl:variable name="successPercent" select="$successCount div $count" />
        <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(../*[@lb = current()/@lb][attribute::tn=$labelCaso]/@t )" />
        <xsl:variable name="averageTime" select="($totalTime div $count)" />
        <xsl:variable name="minTime">
            <xsl:call-template name="min">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="../*[@lb = current()/@lb][attribute::tn=$labelCaso]/@t" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="maxTime">
            <xsl:call-template name="max">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="../*[@lb = current()/@lb][attribute::tn=$labelCaso]/@t" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr valign="top">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$failureCount &gt; 0">Failure</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$label" /> 
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="$failureCount" />
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:call-template name="display-percent">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$successPercent" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:call-template name="display-time">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$averageTime" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:call-template name="display-time">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$minTime" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:call-template name="display-time">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$maxTime" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
        </tr>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Solution found! In the line:

    <tr><xsl:value-of select="$labelCaso" /></tr>

was missing the    

    <td>

Now with the tag, it's working in both, directly in the browser and generated by ant:

    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="$labelCaso" /></td></tr>

thanks.